# Trouble configuring role-based access to AWS key service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I have added full access to all KMS resources to a policy and assigned the policy to a role, which is assigned to an EC2 instance.

I can decrypt ok but when trying to get a data key, it gives...

```
1 validation error detected: Value null at 'keyId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null
```

Why is the key id null when a) I assigned it as a specific resource in the policy and b) I gave access to all resources?

Does the policy only give access but the API call still needs to specify the key?

Comment: did you add the role to the key? its a handshake that needs to go both ways?

Comment: please post the API call that is failing.

Comment: I got it working. I supplied the key id with the API calls. Presumably, the policies only supply credentials and not information about the resources to be used.

Comment: Yup @IanWarburton . You don't need to supply a keyID for decryption, but you'll need one for Generating data keys.